# Line segment relationship in the circle

Tags: geometry

Given $AE=9,EB=8$; $DE:EC= 2:1$

Find $DE$ and $EC$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [power of the point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $E$, you have that 
$$EB\cdot AE= DE\cdot EC$$

Since you know that $AE=9$ and $AB=8$, then $DE\cdot EC=72$. Now, you know too that

$$\frac{DE}{EC}=2$$

So $DE=2EC$, and you have from the first equation that $DE\cdot EC= 2\cdot EC^2=72$, then $EC^2=36$, so $EC=6$ and $DE=12$.

Comment: You're welcome.